# How can i include all child divs into a parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is my parent div not wrapping the content or child divs?

I need all flex-item(child elements) inside the flex-container div.

Here is my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdKYaL).

```css
body {
    background:#ddd;
}
.flex-containerHome {
    height:600px;
    display:table;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.flex-cotainerHead {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.flex-container {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    height:600px;
}
.flex-item:hover {
    background-color: #191975;
}
.flex-item {
    transition:background .5s;
    background: tomato;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-containerHome">
    <div class="flex-cotainerHead">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item">1</div>
            <div class="flex-item">2</div>
            <div class="flex-item">3</div>
            <div class="flex-item">4</div>
            <div class="flex-item">5</div>
            <div class="flex-item">6</div>
            <div class="flex-item">7</div>
            <div class="flex-item">8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="flex-cotainerHead">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item">1</div>
            <div class="flex-item">2</div>
            <div class="flex-item">3</div>
            <div class="flex-item">4</div>
            <div class="flex-item">5</div>
            <div class="flex-item">6</div>
            <div class="flex-item">7</div>
            <div class="flex-item">8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont to flex all items vertically. instead, i want to adjust the width dynamically with CSS.(i mean if i fix the width to 600px. then if i add some more child elements, again child elements will come out of the parent. So i just want to wrap all the child elements inside a Div)

Answer (score 1):

Just add overflow:hidden and change the flex flow to row wrap in the flex container class to make it work.

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shot, here's [my fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjRLpG).

I modified the `.flex-containerHome` to behave as flex as well. I also added `flex: 1 0 auto` to the `.flex-container` element. I also removed the `.flex-cotainerHead` elements

**MODIFIED HTML**

```
<div class="flex-containerHome">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**MODIFIED CSS**

```
.flex-containerHome {
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: But, if I add more parent elements your code is breaking. Here is the fork [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrmXw). I want all the parent divs show side by side. for fixing that i have added `display:table` and `display:inline-block` for my posted code @KiiroSora09

Comment: @user4709780 I updated the implementation in code pen, I added flex-flow: row wrap; for the parent and removed the auto for the flex attribute for the child, also added max-width and min-width so that the children would wrap if more than 2 parents are available. but it's up to you, on how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks for updating, But i am looking to display all the parent elements side by side Horizontally. if there is a overflow it should be hided and i need a scroll bar on the bottom to slide it horizontally.To accomodate that functionality i have added `display:table` and `display:inline-block`. (Simple example is windows 8 home screen, all the groups display side by side horizontally and the user can slide groups) @KiiroSora09

Comment: maybe you can just change flex-flow: row wrap; to flex-flow: row nowrap; in my example, this would force the columns to be side by side, and the horizontal scrollbar woud appear, here is the example in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waXYgy

Comment: how can i make this mobile friendly, i mean if i resize the window it is breaking again.if we set min-width for container, we are restricting the flow  right ?.  by any chance without setting min-width can we make fluid divs ? @KiiroSoa09

Comment: if i add more child elements also it is breaking

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a bummer. if you want to emulate something like the win8 start menu, then maybe we could make the column orientation by row and give the columns a fixed width (flex: 1 0 340px;). Then it's up to you if you would like to give it a fixed height and allow scrollbars to appear or not (for each column that is), just remember to consider width on the columns for the scrollbars when they appear. Non-fixed height example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nqzmyp

Comment: Fixed height example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNKorK. I know this was not what you initially wanted, (you wanted the items organized in columns in each column) but sadly the flex-box model won't expand the width in a columnar approach.

Comment: Oh OKay. Thanks a lot for your time.I appreciate your effort. But i tried something it working perfect in IE11 but not in chrome. Here is my code [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNErQK) Im not sure whats the issue is @KiiroSora09

Comment: @user4709780 in your pen, I think it's still the flex-flow: column wrap; that was the problem, it wont expand when item elements are wrapped. I'm trying something new, can you tell me if the columns will have a fixed height? also if the items have uniform sizes? and lastly, if you could give me the maximum number of items each column could possibly have, it would be great.

Comment: But, if you paste that code in a html file and render it in IE 11 you will see the difference. yes columns have fixed height lets say 550px and items have fixed sizes too (150px). mostly 3 items per column with that fixed height

Comment: Test this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNErQK) in IE 11 you will understand the issue. That pen is working fine in IE but not in other browsers.

Comment: I don't have IE 11 at the moment, but still, what breaks it in other browsers is the columns not expanding according to the content in flex model.

On another note. So each column (by column I mean "flex-container") will a maximum of 3 items?

Comment: yes thats right. on other browsers flex-container columns are not expanding. 3 items is fine.

Comment: If you only need 3 items per column, then: https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/mfgjfupL/

Comment: This is another try (I'm still not tired of this). I found a way, though it's not dynamic. You have to add an .magic element after the last item at each .flex-column, you can find it's CSS at the last part. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/5ugr8etq/

Comment: i see what you did.you are explicitly specifying the width. Thanks again for spending time on this. I will give it a shot i will let you know, if i find another way too.